# convert timestamp from one valid RFC3339 format to another in Go

Tags: go, timestamp

I have timestamps strings in this format `2020-01-17T14:41:56.393+0530` and I want them converted into this format `2019-01-18T04:32:03Z`

The time.Parse method [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) on that godoc says that these are both valid RFC3339 formats but how do I convert them from this form to the Z form?.

Actually want I want to do is find out whether a certain timestamp in this format `2020-01-17T14:41:56.393+0530` lies within a range of two timestamps that are in the z format `2019-01-18T04:32:03Z`

Comment: Change the location to UTC.

Comment: These aren't different formats, just different timezones.

Answer (score 1):

> are both valid RFC3339 formats

The time package defines RFC3339 as:

`RFC3339     = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"`

So `2020-01-17T14:41:56.393+0530` is not valid (there is no colon in the timezone). See [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31113) for a discussion as to whether Go's handling of this is in line with the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339).

> convert them from this form to the Z form

You don't need to - once you have converted to a `time.Time` the package takes care of the timezones for you. For example:

```
checkTime, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05Z0700", "2020-01-17T14:41:56.393+0530")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
startRange, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2020-01-18T02:32:03Z")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
endRange, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2020-01-18T04:32:03Z")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Printf("check: %v start: %v end: %v", checkTime, startRange, endRange)
if !startRange.After(checkTime) && !endRange.Before(checkTime) {
    fmt.Println("Check 1 in range")
}

checkTime, err = time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2020-01-18T09:41:56.393+05:30")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
if !startRange.After(checkTime) && !endRange.Before(checkTime) {
    fmt.Println("Check 2 in range")
}

fmt.Printf("check: %v start: %v end: %v", checkTime.Local(), startRange.Local(), endRange.Local())
```